# An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have one class defined as

```
public class TestRun
{
    [JsonProperty("links")]
    public List<Links> Links { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pid")]
    public string pid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("properties")]
    public List<Properties> Properties { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("test_case")]
    public TestRunCase test_case { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("test_case_version_id")]
    public string test_case_version_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public string page { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("page_size")]
    public string page_size { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public string total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Another part of my code fetches a JSON data string and assigned the converted data to an array

```
TestRun[] RunData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestRun[]>(testrun_Data);
```

Most of time this JSON string of testrun_Data consists of an array of TestRun type of data which is fine. But when it is like what's shown below,

```
{"links":[],"page":1,"page_size":100,"total":0,"items":[]}
```

An exception of type `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` will be thrown.

Comment: Have you tried adding a constructor method to your TestRun class that initializes the properties of type List<T> to a new List<T>? I think what is happening has to do with "links" and "items" in your JSON string being empty arrays.

Comment: Show us the JSON that works.

Comment: If your JSON sometimes consists of an array of objects, and sometimes consists of a single object, you can deserialize to a `List<TestRun>` by using `SingleOrArrayConverter<TestRun>` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182).  (The converters there are specifically for `List<T>` so if you need an array you will need to do `.ToArray()` afterwards.)

Comment: Demo using `SingleOrArrayListConverter` from  [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182) here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m19Q4I

Answer (score 1):

Your provided json string contains an json object, not json array, so you should deserialize it accordingly:

```
TestRun RunData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestRun>(testrun_Data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON looks like this:

```
{"links":[],"page":1,"page_size":100,"total":0,"items":[]}
```

To deserialize it to an array, it would need to look like this:

```
[{"links":[],"page":1,"page_size":100,"total":0,"items":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://json2csharp.com tool to find the object where the json can be deserialized.